# Control VLC player using python-vlc module

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

Controlling the VLC media player using python-vlc module

I have tried the code below but am getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>
> ```
> import vlc   File "vlc.py", line 2, in <module>
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MediaPlayer'

Using code:

```
import vlc
    media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer("path_to_your_song.mp3")
    media_player.play()
```

I want the script to run and play the file

Answer (score 2):

Just change the **path**,your good to go..

```
from vlc import Instance
import time
import os

class VLC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Player = Instance('--loop')

    def addPlaylist(self):
        self.mediaList = self.Player.media_list_new()
        path = r"C:\Users\dell5567\Desktop\engsong"
        songs = os.listdir(path)
        for s in songs:
            self.mediaList.add_media(self.Player.media_new(os.path.join(path,s)))
        self.listPlayer = self.Player.media_list_player_new()
        self.listPlayer.set_media_list(self.mediaList)
    def play(self):
        self.listPlayer.play()
    def next(self):
        self.listPlayer.next()
    def pause(self):
        self.listPlayer.pause()
    def previous(self):
        self.listPlayer.previous()
    def stop(self):
        self.listPlayer.stop()
```

Create a object

```
player = VLC()
```

Add playlist

```
player.addPlaylist()
```

Play the song

```
player.play()
time.sleep(9)
```

Play the next song

```
player.next()
time.sleep(9)
```

Pause the song

```
player.pause()
time.sleep(9)
```

Resume the song

```
player.play()
time.sleep(9)
```

Previous song

```
player.previous()
time.sleep(9)
```

Stop the song

```
player.stop()
```

Comment: I tried this solution and worked perfectly for me. Now I was wondering, after using player.play() if I want to use player.pause() or player.stop() asynchronously, what will be the best approach? For example: I was thinking, if I create separate modules for play, pause, stop etc where I will import individual methods from this class. But the problem will be how to use the same player instance in different modules. so, I was looking for the best pythonic way to do that

Comment: I guess you can use inheritance concepts. Create a class with init method only and derive all other classes from main class.

Comment: I've seen a couple ways to instantiate a new player including `mediaplayer = vlc.MediaPlayer()`. Where are the docs for these bindings? Super useful, but virtually undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a vlc `Instance`.
The minimum required would be something like this, but there are many variations.

```
>>> import vlc
>>> i = vlc.Instance()
>>> media_player = i.media_player_new()
>>> media_player.set_mrl('./vp1.mp3')
>>> media_player.play()
```

Comment: Sir I tried this code but I am getting following error using Python2.7 on Windows 7 ultimateTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\vlc3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "C:\Python27\vlc.py", line 207, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Python27\vlc.py", line 167, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found

Comment: @anita I don't use windows so I am unable to give you any real hint as to what the issue is. However, this vlc unrelated question may provide a clue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804438/find-library-in-ctypes On the downside I don't see how you code posted in the question would have worked either if the code I posted is in the same directory. Have you tried using just the 5 lines of code above in the directory that contains the `vlc.py` program.