# How to make a Python requests.Response object byte-like?

Tags: python, string, python-requests, byte

I've downloaded a small .mp3 file from the net using Python's requests module, like this:

```
file_on_disk = open(filename, 'wb')
write(downloaded_file.content)
file_on_disk.close()
```

Now it works fine on the disk as an MP3 file should. However, I'd like to play it using python-vlc's MediaPlayer while it's still not written to disk, i.e. from memory. However, this doesn't work:

```
vlc.MediaPlayer(downloaded_file.content).play()
```

I get a `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` message. I checked the type of the content and `type(downloaded_file.content)` identifies it as <class 'bytes'>, not str. The same MediaPlayer nicely plays the file once it's saved to the disk. What am I missing here, and how can I convert the file in-memory to a format that vlc.MediaPlayer is able to play?

(I'm a beginner so the answer might be obvious, but it keeps eluding me.)

edit: my full code is actually:

```
import requests, vlc
downloaded_file = requests.get('https://cdn.duden.de/_media_/audio/ID4111733_460321137.mp3')
from vlc import MediaPlayer
MediaPlayer(downloaded_file.content).play()
```

Comment: Try `bytes(downloaded_file.content)`.

Comment: forgot to say that I actually tried this before posting, and it didn't work.

Comment: It should work — how did it not? What was the error?

Comment: @martineau I also find it strange, I try to play `bytes(downloaded_file.content)` and I still get a `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` error.

Comment: It might work by converting the string into a [`io.ByteIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object and pass that to `vlc` as the "file".

Comment: @martineau no, in this case I get an `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO` error

Comment: That error message sounds like it wants a string (or bytes or PathLike) object that specifies a path to a file to play — which implies something different than the one you mentioned in your question…and may mean that `vlc` only works with files, not streams of data in memory. You may have no choice but to save it to disk first. You should be able to use the `tempfile` module to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623123/control-vlc-player-using-python-vlc-module) possibly related question, you need to create a vlc `Instance`.

Comment: this unfortunately didn't work, I get the same response